# How to restrict two WebSocket endpoints to different controllers?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket

To illustrate the problem, imagine two endpoints, E1 and E2, and 4 controllers, C1, C2, C3 and C4. How can I restrict E1 to only send messages to C1 and C2 and E2 to C3 and C4?

Answer (score 0):

You can find many examples online. If you are Dev. RESTful services with spring boot,. Then you can use annotations

@GetMapping
@PostMappinh
Etc...

You can specify the desired route with this annotations.

This is something spring.io  already provided in there docs. Link demonstrating how to do it properly
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/